How to move Resources in Godot from a script without breaking references
I need to be able to programmatically move Resource files in Godot without breaking all scenes that reference those Resources.
I know moving files by hand in the editor doesn't cause this issue, but for my use case, it's important that files be moved by a script rather than by hand.
Is there an API for moving files without breaking scenes that reference them?
